# How to make FeignClient use name over url?

Tags: java, spring, netflix, feign

I have a @FeignClient interface:

```
@FeignClient(name="${some.service.id}", url="${some.service.url}")
public interface SomeInterface {
...
}
```

My question is- **how can I direct feign to use one of the two properties (name/url)?** I left the url property empty in the production properties file, but it seems as if it **always uses the url property.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So eventually I found a suitable solution here:
[Define different Feign client implementations based on environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43977983/define-different-feign-client-implementations-based-on-environment)

Although I wanted to solve this using only one feign client with configuration and profiles, I didn't find a way to do it. This solution is based on creating two different feign clients, each will be used in the right profile.